# RTCICEConnectionFailed swift

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, libjingle, starscream

I'm trying to achieve audio calling with WebRTC. The pods I have are:

```
pod 'Starscream', '~> 2.0.4'
pod 'libjingle_peerconnection'
```

When I try to send SDP received as an answer, it got failed. I'm here providing selected lines of code as it's too lengthy.

1. Connect Socket

   ```
   self.socket?.connect()
   ```
2. As socket get connected status, initialize WebRTC

   ```
   func initalizeWebRTC() -> Void {
   print("----------------initalizeWebRTC----------------")

   RTCPeerConnectionFactory.initializeSSL()
   self.webRtcClient  = RTCPeerConnectionFactory.init()
   let stunServer = self.defaultStunServer()
   let defaultConstraint = self.createDefaultConstraint()
   self.peerConnection = self.webRtcClient?.peerConnection(withICEServers: [stunServer], constraints: defaultConstraint, delegate: self)

   self.localVideoView.delegate = self
   self.remoteVideoView.delegate = self
   // webrtc initalized local rendering of video on
   self.addLocalMediaStrem()

   }
   ```
3. Here are my configurations

   ```
   func defaultStunServer() -> RTCICEServer {
   print("----------------defaultStunServer----------------")
   let url = URL.init(string: stunServer);
   let iceServer = RTCICEServer.init(uri: url, username: "", password: "")
   return iceServer!
   }

   func createAudioVideoConstraints() -> RTCMediaConstraints{
   print("----------------createAudioVideoConstraints----------------")
   let audioOffer : RTCPair = RTCPair(key: "OfferToReceiveAudio", value: "true")
   let videoOffer : RTCPair = RTCPair(key: "OfferToReceiveVideo", value: "false")
   let dtlsSrtpKeyAgreement : RTCPair = RTCPair(key: "DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", value: "true")

   let connectConstraints : RTCMediaConstraints = RTCMediaConstraints.init(mandatoryConstraints: [audioOffer,videoOffer], optionalConstraints: [dtlsSrtpKeyAgreement])

   return connectConstraints
   }

   func createDefaultConstraint() -> RTCMediaConstraints {
   print("----------------createDefaultConstraint----------------")
     let dtlsSrtpKeyAgreement : RTCPair = RTCPair(key: "DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", value: "true")
   let connectConstraints : RTCMediaConstraints = RTCMediaConstraints.init(mandatoryConstraints: nil, optionalConstraints: [dtlsSrtpKeyAgreement])

   return connectConstraints
   }
   ```
4. Create offer using WebRTC

   ```
   self.peerConnection?.createOffer(with: self, constraints: constraint)
   ```
5. Write data to socket

   ```
   let offerDict =  ["id":"joinRoomPresenter","name":fileName,"roomName":fileName,"isFrontCamera":"false","isMicroPhone":"false","isPhoneAudio":"false","isChat":"false","isOneToOneSession":"false","accessToken":"9289010e-d2d5-42e8-a95c-212f06aa9238","userId":"3459","fileName":fileName,"portalId":voiceCallID,"personName":fileName,"photoURL":"","sdpOffer":sdp.description] as [String : Any]
   socket?.write(string: offerDict.json)
   ```
6. On success, I received sip as a message from socket.

> ["sdpAnswer": v=0
>
> o=- 544328641767753251 2 IN IP4 104.248.181.233
>
> s=VideoRoom 2623889018315199
>
> t=0 0
>
> a=group:BUNDLE audio
>
> a=msid-semantic: WMS janus
>
> m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111
>
> c=IN IP4 104.248.181.233
>
> a=recvonly
>
> a=mid:audio
>
> a=rtcp-mux
>
> a=ice-ufrag:SJ8U
>
> a=ice-pwd:72CaTpbKHUzwWj7rX64cGn
>
> a=ice-options:trickle
>
> a=fingerprint:sha-256 13:2A:57:AA:FC:AE:2B:44:86:1A:FD:FD:77:4A:11:BD:78:60:A3:4E:D1:98:3C:43:1C:71:82:C7:88:EE:01:CC
>
> a=setup:active
>
> a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
>
> a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
>
> a=msid:janus janusa0
>
> a=ssrc:1319411670 cname:janus
>
> a=ssrc:1319411670 msid:janus janusa0
>
> a=ssrc:1319411670 mslabel:janus
>
> a=ssrc:1319411670 label:janusa0
>
> a=candidate:1 1 udp 2013266431 104.248.181.233 57307 typ host
>
> a=candidate:2 1 udp 2013266430 10.46.0.9 56250 typ host
>
> a=end-of-candidates
>
> , "id": joinRoomPresenterResponse, "response": accepted]

7. I send the same sdp as an answer

   ```
   self.peerConnection?.setRemoteDescriptionWith(self, sessionDescription: rtcSessionDesc!)
   ```
8. I got the iceGathering state Changed to 2 (gathering). but after some seconds, iceConnection state Changed to 4 (failed)

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Did you used the new library GoogleWebRTC pod or still working with the pod 'libjingle_peerconnection' ?? and were you successful in sending the Data

Answer (score 3):

For starters, libjingle is pretty old (2016). I would try the GoogleWebRTC pod, it is constantly updated from their repo.

In the socket send you have "isMicroPhone":"false","isPhoneAudio":"false"
If it's a voice shouldn't those be true?

I would try Googles main example app and go from there. Getting all the steps correct with a webrtc connection is difficult sometimes.

Comment: I was using the libjingle library but we could't transmit messages through the data channel, should I use GoogleWebRTC pod?